# Stopping processor in secure NiFi

Tags: ssl, groovy, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi

I have  secure NiFi (with self signed  SSL certificate) and I have already made SSL context service for SSL handshake. I need to use REST API for stropping NiFi processors inside my invokehttp processor I use :

1. URL like - https://server ip/nifi-api/processors/420a850d-7042-359f-c16c-6c0de285b209
2. StandardSSLContext Service
3. Basic Authentication username and  password
4. I  have added  Authorization attribute inside my invokehttp processor with bearer  token

But it still shows this exception :

> Java.net.SocketTimeoutException.

There is one  more subject  I am interested in, If self-signed certificate's issuer is another  person for  example - Tim, can I also use this certificate and truststore with my basic authentication parameters (username and password  to use REST API)?

Can someone give me any better idea on how can I get rid of this SocketTimeout exception?

Comment: `http://localhost:8080` is wrong for secured nifi - please modify.

Comment: sure   my server ip is diiferent  from  this    ,  i diin't  pay  attention on  url   when i  have posted  it ,but in case of  right  url i  hve  the  same  problem too

Comment: did you tried another tools to connect this url? try to use `curl --verbose URL` it will print the detailed information how it connects to server and add the result to your question. `SocketTimeoutException` not connected to SSL.

Comment: in case  of  curl it  works  but  i wnat to  make  connection via  nifi  workflow

Comment: I have  many processors   which i  want to stop  or  start  and  if  i use  curl  i  will have  to  write  and  save  inside   nifi  folders  as many ssh  file  with  curl  command  as many processors's  state  i want to  change, and  in this  case  i think it will make my  nifi  performance  worse

Comment: Is  it possible  that, inside nifi configuration my  user isn't allowed  to access nifi processoirs  by rest  api, i mean  is  it  possible  that  my  user  doesn't  have as many rights  as  possible  for such connection

Comment: there is  also one  detail in  ssl context service i use self-signed  certificate   which  isn't  issued  on my name and in  basic  autentification i use  my username and password ( so i think in  this  case i use   insecure connections) this  can be  reson for  socket  timeout  exception?

Comment: In case  of    curl comands  this works:

Comment: token=$(curl 'https://nifi-server:9091/nifi-api/access/token' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' --data 'username=username&password=password' --compressed --insecure --tlsv1.2)
#echo token = $token
 
# Get the latest version of the flow
version=$(curl 'https://nifi-server:9091/nifi-api/processors/62c34df2-015b-1000-89e3-e2e77533331e' -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$token'' --compressed --insecure --tlsv1.2 | awk -F'[/:]' '{print $4}' | head -c2)
#echo version = $version

Comment: curl 'https://nifi-server:9091/nifi-api/processors/62c34df2-015b-1000-89e3-e2e77533331e' -X PUT -H 'Host: nifi-ambari-02:9091' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://nifi-ambari-02:9091/nifi/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$token'' -H 'X-1000-89e3-e2e77533331e","state":"STOPPED"}}' --insecure --tlsv1.2

Comment: Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data '{"revision":{"clientId":"6386076d-015b-1000-2a22-714f84689191","version":'$version'},"component":{"id":"62c34df2-015b-

Comment: I will try curl --verbose URL  this too

Comment: I  have  tried  this  curl  verbose  and   get error  which tells me  that SEC_ERROR_CA_CERT_INVALID,  what should i  do , should i make new  certificate or  is there any way  i can edit  some  data

Comment: Bytheway  do  you  know any command  which  can  help me see details  of my error?